# Remote Images not displaying after running Magmi

Tags: magento-1.7, magmi

I've installed Magmi, configured it and installed it too

Iam able to get products into my site, BUT prob is: Iam unable to see any image, since image urls all are from remote..

My image url looks like: http://www.fashion58.com/itemimages/SMS032-navy.jpg

Even iam not sure whether to change 'image renaming' or not, BUT at end all I need is : my remore image urls should able to display in my site..

Awaiting response!

**EDITED**: 
**My feed Column names are:**  `store,websites,type,attribute_set,is_affiliate_product,status,visibility,qty,is_in_stock,tax_class_id,weight,name,meta_keyword,description,sku,manufacturer,price,merchant_buy_link,image,main_category,color,for,shoe_type,short_description,thumbnail,category_ids,merchant_name,merchant_id,small_image`

**A)** and Do I really need to use '**Image attributes processor**' plugin inorder to display remote image urls?  or else Magmi just enough to render images for remote image urls?

**B)** If YES for '**Image attributes processor**', what settings I need to change in it?

**C)** What could be still wrong?

Comment: please anyone can answer this..?

Comment: Hey Joey, I followed your sample URL and it redirects to the product detail page, it's not an image. Can you please bring more light on 1) how exactly your image URLs look 2) why you need image renaming

Comment: @Rob : Iam sorry i given a wrong link above.. now i given my image link..(pls kindly check above again) actually i dont know whether i should change 'image renaming' or someother seting.. All I need is:  My remote image urls should able to display..

Comment: @Rob  my feed has remote image urls, and column names related to image are: remote_image_url and  remote_thumbnail_image_url

Comment: now I renamed these 2 columns "remote_image_url and remote_thumbnail_image_url "  to "image and thumbnail" , even then iamm not getting images displayed on my site from feed.

Comment: I think you're using wrong column headers. Try simple "image", "small_image", "thumbnail" and point in there your remote urls as is and try to re-import. And no need to use "renaming". Honestly, I didn't ever use it yet, this may be causing the troubles.

Comment: @Rob  I just edited above in my main post, could you please read that again!

Comment: a possible reason is that your hosting might disable outbound http connection. Try this checking php script `<?php echo file_get_contents('http://www.google.com'); ?>` in your browser. Does it display content of google page or blank?

Comment: @Rob I guess i need to do use Column mapper (since my csv column names having bit differnt)
what all column changes i need to make if i use 'column mapper' plugin..

Comment: seriously, make sure that it's able to download remote image through http at all. Try that snippet.

Comment: @Rob : yyour snippet redirected to google.com BUT image of google didnt displayed.. do you think is that causing me trouble..?

Comment: many chances that there is some restriction for outbound http traffic on your hosting, firewall or something. To make sure, try this with one of your images from the feed `file_get_contents('http://your.image/path.png');`

Comment: @Rob : I given code as: <?php echo file_get_contents('http://fashion58.com/itemimages/SMS032-navy.jpg'); ?>  and please check output as: http://shoesdino.com/magmitest/testgoogle.php

is that correct output iam getting? or your line of code should display image?

Comment: the output is fine... I'm about to give up. The only possible issue is maybe image renaming messes up? Give a try to leaving it blank. That's the last thing which comes to mind. Apart from it everything looks fine. Well, you can also try learning `magmi/state/trace.txt`, if your import generates some exceptions they must be logged there. I'd like to look into this, but not sure if there is PM on this site to get in touch there.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a third party module, please contact them directly for support.

Answer (score 0):

Your link that your image is at should be entered in your .csv file as:

http://fashion58.com/itemimages/SMS032-navy.jpg

And yes the image attribute checkbox should be selected when uploading images. There are no settings for this option, simply a checkbox to select?

For more info work through below url:

http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=Image_attributes_processor

Comment: I just tried as you said, i mean i removed "www" for all images an re-imported again, and also checked for plugin "Image attributes processor" , even after doing all these iam unabe to get images for products...  Not understanding what to do :(

Comment: Hi Joey, it's really hard to work out what's going wrong. Sounds like you are doing everything correct now to be honest. Have you had success at pulling in images locally from your media/import folder? I recall it was "fiddly" to configure pulling in images via Magmi remotely around 9 months ago, but the method I've described above is what we use now. We pull from 3rd party sites regularly rather than our own. Might be wrong, but it could be because your image labels are missing? E.g. image_label, small_image_label, thumbnail_label, you could try adding those in, product name as image labels.